# jQuery, on click scroll window down to top of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my browser window scroll down to the top of a div when clicked. The only problem is everything else works but that, the window should scroll down to the top of the div clicked...

So far I have:

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
    $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500);
    $(window).scrollTop;
});
```

I've made a jsfiddle to show you what I mean... 
http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with $(window).scrollTop?

Comment: animating same element two times????????

Comment: @Alex `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: loooooooolllllllllllllllll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/7/

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
   $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
   $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500).promise().done(function(){
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},500);
       $(this).addClass('current').unbind('click'); // just add this line
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai, once the animation is complete, is there a way to stop the function reoccuring if the same div is clicked?

Comment: `if($(window).scrollTop()==0) { return false; }` @Liam

Comment: what do you want? you want only the div to be clicked once and also the event to execute only once and after one time, that event should be disabled?

Comment: If you see here http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/4/ where the element moves to the top of the window if you click it again it animates, whereas i dont want that to animate, if that makes sense? @AspiringAqib

Comment: yeah ofcourse that makes sense :D I got it, if the div is already opened like the white space between any div then do not animate :D

Comment: well i made it but gonna post it as a new Answer :P Should i? or give you directly the link of it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22391/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-liam)

Comment: @Liam Late reply! checkout updated the answer and the fiddle. check this one plz

Comment: @Jai It works for a few times but after then it stucks hahahah :P and some time the div get animated more than one time :P

Comment: @Jai Mine one is little nasty but still works better than your one! Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/8/

Comment: beautiful! I changed it to `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 400},500);` to get what I wanted

Answer (score 8):

This is how you scroll to the top of the div as long as the window isn't maxed out:

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

I am unsure what you were trying to achieve before scrolling

See it here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
    $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jq4Vw/4/

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
   $('.work-showcase').animate({height:'135px'}, 500);
  $(this).animate({height:'400px'}, 500,function() {  
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top });  
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.work-showcase').click(function(){
    window.location = "#top";
});
```

make sure top ID is present.

```
<div id="top">
I am at the top of the document.
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyAMX/)

Comment: window.location is not a method but a property. BTW i cannot see how this can be an answer

Comment: @roasted He is redirecting to other page :D. Let the user not see anything while clicking it. Everyone is answering so he also answered one.

Comment: hahaha :P you noobs :P you do not know that he is using `hash` method! He is doing correct but the other users must have brain to know how use it :/

Comment: @Zeal Murapa +1 for giving these users an idea that they are not always correct ;)